# Richtextbox Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, object, reference, richtextbox, instance

Why am I getting this error? My program is using .NET4 Framework. And I got this error below: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
   if (this.webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("/fire/") && this.richTextBox1.Text.Contains("-"))
            this.richTextBox1.Text = this.richTextBox1.Text.Substring(0, this.richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf('-'));
```

And so I revised it and changed it to this one below and it still won't work:

```
               if (webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("/fire/") && richTextBox1.Text.Contains("-"))  {richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(0, richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf('-'));}
```

Here is the true body of that code:

```
   private void button64_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.richTextBox2.Refresh();
        this.richTextBox1.Refresh();
        if (object.Equals((object)this.richTextBox1.Text, (object)this.richTextBox2.Text))
            this.label1.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
        if (!object.Equals((object)this.richTextBox1.Text, (object)this.richTextBox2.Text))
            this.label1.BackColor = Color.Orchid;

        if (this.webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("/fire/") && this.richTextBox1.Text.Contains("-"))
            this.richTextBox1.Text = this.richTextBox1.Text.Substring(0, this.richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf('-'));
        if (this.webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("hell.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/OrderSummaryDisplay?") && this.richTextBox1.Text.Contains(","))
            this.richTextBox1.Text = this.richTextBox1.Text.Substring(0, this.richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(','));
        if (this.webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("hell.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/OrderSummaryDisplay?") && this.richTextBox2.Text.Contains(","))
            this.richTextBox2.Text = this.richTextBox2.Text.Substring(0, this.richTextBox2.Text.IndexOf(','));
        if (this.richTextBox1.Text.Contains("-") && !this.richTextBox2.Text.Contains("-"))
            this.richTextBox2.Text = this.richTextBox2.Text.Substring(0, this.richTextBox2.Text.IndexOf('-'));
        if (!this.richTextBox2.Text.Contains("-") || this.richTextBox1.Text.Contains("-"))
            return;
        this.richTextBox2.Text = this.richTextBox2.Text.Substring(0, this.richTextBox2.Text.IndexOf('-'));

    }
```

Comment: yes, but how do I fix it, i don't see anything wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough detail in your question to be sure, but you get that error when you're trying to access a property of an object that's null.

Either place a breakpoint on the line of code you indicated and check each object to see if it's null, or change your code to check for nulls:

```
if (webBrowser1.Url != null && webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("/fire/") && .... )
```